# pre_get_posts dont firing... Anybody knows whats the wrong with my code?

Tags: pre-get-posts

I trying exclude category "1" with pre_get_posts:

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
    if( !is_admin() && $query->is_home() && $query->is_front_page() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_tag() && $query->is_search())
    {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-1' ); // I also trying without the '' on the -1 (cat id)
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

I'am use on my pages the main query:

```
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

Comment: Try adding `wp_die('hello');` in the IF statement to see if it even hits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your condition:

A single query cannot match all of your conditions - it can't be a `tag` as well as `search`, for example. You need to use `||` (or) and possibly nest - so for example,

```
if(!is_admin() && ($query->is_home() || $query->is_search())) {
```

This says, "if we're not in the admin area AND either it's a home query or a search query, then do this."

Also, some of the `is_` conditions you're trying to meet aren't the way you test the query. `is_front_page()` cannot be called because the query isn't set up yet - but `is_home()` can. [Read up in the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Exclude_categories_on_your_main_page) to learn more about which conditionals are valid, and then you can try a simplified query first - such as `if(!is_admin())` to make sure it's running - then add additional conditions one at a time so you can tell which one specifically is causing you problems.